# Chat API - Similar service like TokBox but for text-based chat?

Tags: chat, real-time, text-based

I find tokbox is a great service for video chat. But is there any other similar service for text-based chat, that provides api, so that i can manage my own users and chat participants.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In another SO question somebody recommended http://www.phpfreechat.net/ but I've no experience of using the service.

As ever Google is your friend and once you know of a service such as PHP Free Chat you can do a [related search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?as_rq=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.phpfreechat.net%2F&q=related%3A+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.phpfreechat.net%2F&hl=en&biw=1440&bih=723&btnG=Search) and get some other options.

You could also build a chat solution using [Pusher](http://pusher.com), who I work for. We offer a number of [publisher libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries) and [client libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries) in different technologies including JavaScript. We offer [presence functionality](http://pusher.com/docs/presence) that makes building chat forums really easy which is why it's one of the big use of Pusher.

**Edit**

There is also [CometChat](http://kevinrohling.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/world-domination-using-arduinos-and-websockets/) which may be worth looking at.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I have used Pusher before for another product. It's really ease to use. Unfortunately, pusher is using websocket with flash fallback, which is hard to deploy on mobile devices. I know that the discussion of websocket and long polling are everywhere. Each one has its own advandtage and drawback. That's the reason i want to find a managed server that provide everything i need so that i don't have to care about the implementation

Comment: Is PHP Free Chat the type of thing you are looking for? Sounds like it uses HTTP Polling (AJAX). Or are you looking for native mobile support? e.g. Objective-C, Java for Android etc.

Comment: i am using phonegap to create app for mobile devices. Right now i'm using PubNub for other real time collaboration  task. PubNub works greate across all devices i deploy (blackberry, playbook, android, iphone, bada, and also web) But since PubNub is not cheap, i don't want to use its service for chat. That's the reason why i'm looking for other chat service